# Ошибка подготавливаемого запроса SQL

Tags: php, sql

Пишу код подготовленный запрос:

```
$queryMask = "SELECT (`id`, CONCAT(?) AS NAME, MATCH(?) AGAINST(?) AS RELEV) FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(?) AGAINST(?) ORDER BY RELEV DESC";

// подготавливаем запрос
$this->stmt = $this->db->prepare($queryMask);
if (!($this->stmt))
    throw new SearchException(3, "Error set prepare request: ".$this->db->error);
```

А вывод кидает исключение:

```
Error set prepare request: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS NAME, MATCH(?) AGAINST(?) AS RELEV) FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(?) AGAINST(?) O' at line 1.
```

Уже всю голову сломал, не пойму никак,что ему не нравится?

UPD #1:
Прикол ещё в том, что запрос вида

```
SELECT `id`, CONCAT(`rusname`, ' (',`origname`,') [',`year`,']') AS NAME, MATCH(`rusname`,`origname`,`year`) AGAINST('>(+пира +моря +свет) (пира* моря* свет*)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS RELEV FROM `films` WHERE MATCH(`rusname`,`origname`,`year`) AGAINST('>(+пира +моря +свет) (пира* моря* свет*)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY RELEV DESC;
```

проходит без проблем. Магия.

UPD #2:
Похоже все-таки не мой день. Решил проблему использованием простого и родного query(), а на всякие модные заморочки вроде prepare() решил забить ибо так и непонятно что же ему надо.

Comment: А запрос работает, если подставить имена?

Comment: И даже если подставлю имена, тоже не работает...

Comment: диалект SQL какой?

Comment: Хз, стоит обычная MySQL 5.1.58 база.

Comment: А-а, pdo'шники же) А не пробовали execute там вызвать перед проверкой? Явно ж видно, что запрос вызывается в том виде, в котором есть.

Comment: Зачем там execute? Я проверял наличие statement object.

Comment: наличие проверяется через `var_dump` или `false === $this->stmt`. Вообще, факт в том, что запрос у вас уходит в базу. Возможно, вы не все строки привели или ваш stmt пытается послать запрос в методе `__toString`. Тут я. честно, уже не в курсе, но *без посылки запроса ошибку запроса вам выдать не могут*.

Comment: Хм.. Цитата из доков: 
mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.
http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В MySQL в prepared statements можно устанавливать placeholder'ы только вместо значений, но не вместо имен таблиц, полей или управляющих структур. Т.е. такое выражение `SELECT a FROM tbl WHERE b = ?` будет корректно, а `SELECT ? FROM tbl WHERE a = 3` уже нет.

Дело в том, что prepared statements, как видно из названия, подгатавливаются к исполнению еще на этапе подготовки запроса и к этому моменту MySQL уже нужно знать какие таблицы и поля будут использоваться, что бы заранее рассчитать стратегию выполнения запроса.

Comment: А с выражением в AGAINST как поступать?

Answer (score 2):

А зачем скобки в SELECT?

Попробуй так:

```
SELECT `id`, CONCAT(?) AS NAME, MATCH(?) AGAINST(?) AS RELEV
FROM `table`
WHERE MATCH(?) AGAINST(?)
ORDER BY RELEV DESC;
```

Comment: Не, так не работает. Собственно, я скобки и поставил, после того, как не заработало без скобок.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, вам будет интересно [это](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46144). Мне почему-то кажется, что это не первый запрос и вы не закрыли предыдщее prepare. То есть запрос должен быть либо выполнен, либо очищен. Если и это не поможет - в каменты пишем минимальный код для отлова ошибки. (connect, prepare, ваш запрос)

**UPDATE** В общем, я немного каюсь, ибо косяк все-таки в match. Как это понял я: запрос проверяется не только на синтаксическую верность, но и на наличие FULLTEXT индекса для полей в части MATCH. То есть, для нормального функционирования надо в MATCH добавить список полей.

ЗЫ: я вообще не фанат всяких PDO, потому эта штука была чужда совсем.

ЗЗЫ: вот ваш запрос

```
SELECT `id`, CONCAT(?) AS NAME, MATCH(`rusname`,`origname`,`year`) AGAINST(?) AS RELEV FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(`rusname`,`origname`,`year`) AGAINST(?) ORDER BY RELEV DESC
```

Comment: В том то и дело, что это первый запрос.

Код написан в шапке, в коннекте моём нет ничего особенного, всё обычно. Ругается именно на MATCH(?) AGAINST(?)... Даже из консоли не сразу запустило (upd #1).

Comment: Ммм видимо, я очень незаметно обновил ответ) @ReklatsMasters , проверьте плз

Comment: $_mask = "ваш запрос";
if ($this->db->prepare($_mask))
    throw new SearchException(7," not work");
else
    throw new SearchException(7,"work");

Выкидывает "not work". 
Это не PDO, а mysqli. Я сам не стал разбираться с PDO ибо mysqli как то роднее и проще.

Comment: Так это mysqli o_O И вы условия перепутали)) все работает. Перечсотрите ваш комментарий)

Comment: Оставьте, право, эти заморочки.

Comment: Не не, я заметил, что перепутал условия тут)) У себя в тесте я всё нормально написал и перепроверил. Не работает.

Answer (score 1):

```
$queryMask = "SELECT `id`, CONCAT(?) AS NAME, MATCH(?), AGAINST(?) AS RELEV FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(?) and AGAINST(?) ORDER BY RELEV DESC";
```

ну возможно что ты с пунктуацией не подружился :) ну и скобки нафиг

Comment: Хм. Ваш вариант даже в сонсоли не работает. Между MATCH и AGAINST не должно быть ничего. Возможно не мой день (неделя?).